# Better use of lsof in Linux?

Tags: linux, lsof

I'm looking for a way to list open files by the Flash plugin (whether Firefox or Chrome). I could use `lsof | grep Flash`, and it works. But I'm looking for a more efficient way to do that, using `lsof` arguments, rather than listing all the files and then filtering them. Any idea?

Comment: man lsof. lsof -c <Porgramname>

Answer (score 0):

Having a short look at the manpage which you can display by typing: **man lsof** tells me that maybe the *-c* Option might be the one you are looking for. I tried that by using the commannd with:

```
lsof -c firefox
```

for example. As for the beginning of how to use lsof i recommend this site:
http://www.catonmat.net/blog/unix-utilities-lsof/